# Encode file with cmd

Tags: encoding, command-line, utf-8

I have a bat file that performs some actions and I need to encode a text file with UTF-8 format.
Is there any way to perform this in windows command line??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with other programs which may or may not be installed. If you're targetting Windows 7 and higher you could just use PowerShell:

```
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" somefile.txt
```

Comment: Well, yes, PowerShell has a hefty startup time, sadly. It's much, much better on an SSD. You might consider moving the script completely to PowerShell, though.